# A melancholic melody

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music

Have you ever, Ray, hit the floor.
Hard times, still waiting, still worth fighting for.
It ends tonight, go, fingers crossed.

Face everything and rise, savior, Hellman.
Live forever, so much better, Pepper, Iron man.
Done is done, tonight the world dies. Let it be.

[...]

To solve this tune, it isn't so simple,
Even if the lyrics, aren't that subtle,
Can you tell me who is mimicked and what's plagiarized?

Hint:

> The King of the Woods

Comment: Going Hamateur's answer is as close a hint for anyone to find this - Not wanting to discourage new answers - I'm not dead or anything, and will accept the correct answer if it's ever given : )

Answer (score 5):

Well it seems to be focused around

> Milencolin: done is done, pepper,  hellman, ray, hard times, fingers crossed.

Which sadly I am not an expert on, further analysis

> brandy, millencolin, linkin park 
> Millencolin, sum 41, my darkest days. 
> all american rejects, (various artists), millencolin.
>  
> papa roach, rise against, millencolin. 
> Oasis, eminem, millencolin, ozzy
> millencolin, papa roach, beatles.

It will be rather difficult for me to find the actual (song?) being (recreated?). but I like the title. Might work further... but not an area of expertise.

Comment: Definitly on the right track! Now you need to find the answer to what's mimicked or plagiarized!  - *Your list of artists doesn't exactly match mine (because let's face it titles get shared), but it's similar enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on

> The Marvel Characters

Have you ever, Ray, hit the floor.

> Beta Ray Bill, an alien granted a Mjolnir by All-Father Odin.

Hard times, still waiting, still worth fighting for.
It ends tonight, go, fingers crossed.

> Ragnarok, the end of all things.

Face everything and rise, savior, Hellman.
Live forever, so much better, Pepper, Iron man.

> Tony Stark and Pepper Potts

Done is done, tonight the world dies. Let it be.

> Implying the finality of Ragnarok.

To solve this tune, it isn't so simple,
 Even if the lyrics, aren't that subtle,
 Can you tell me who is mimicked and what's plagiarized?

> Man creating weapons to mimic The End is mimicked; Ragranok is plagarized.

Comment: Good attempt but I'm afraid it's quite far off.